# Java. Массивы. Нужен метод проверяющий победителя в крестики нолики

Tags: java, массивы, циклы

У меня игра крестики-нолики. Мне нужно проверить есть ли 3 одинаковых символа подряд. Проблемой для меня стало то что в игре возможен выбор размера поля. Да и даже то что получилось для поля 3х3 мне кажется каким-то не красивым.

```
private static boolean checkWinner(String[][] desc) {
    return checkWinnerHorizontal(desc) ||
            checkWinnerVertical(desc) ||
            checkWinnerDiagonals(desc);
}

private static boolean checkWinnerHorizontal(String[][] desc) {
    return desc[0][0].equals(desc[1][0]) && desc[0][0].equals(desc[2][0]) ||
            desc[0][1].equals(desc[1][1]) && desc[0][1].equals(desc[2][1]) ||
            desc[0][2].equals(desc[1][2]) && desc[0][2].equals(desc[2][2]);
}

private static boolean checkWinnerVertical(String[][] desc) {
    return desc[0][0].equals(desc[0][1]) && desc[0][0].equals(desc[0][2]) ||
            desc[1][0].equals(desc[1][1]) && desc[1][0].equals(desc[1][2]) ||
            desc[2][0].equals(desc[2][1]) && desc[2][0].equals(desc[2][2]);
}

private static boolean checkWinnerDiagonals(String[][] desc) {
    return desc[0][0].equals(desc[1][1]) && desc[0][0].equals(desc[2][2]) ||
            desc[2][0].equals(desc[1][1]) && desc[2][0].equals(desc[0][2]);
}
```

Как-то это все топорно надо что-бы коротко и красиво было помогите пожалуйста, не кодом так идеей как это можно сделать, с учетом что мы не знаем размер поля, известно только что это квадрат. Как-то циклами надо...

Comment: ну, да, есть же циклы :)

Comment: а можно поинтересоваться, почему вы используете массив String, а не char?

Comment: >>>а можно поинтересоваться, почему вы используете массив String, а не char?<<< потому что стормозил)))

Comment: @Павел а как вам вообще на деле поможет `true` или `false` (особенно учитывая что ряд из пустых клеток тоже выдаст `true`)? Разве не нужно точно знать кто победил, и что "победили" не пустые клетки?

Comment: ))) да пустые клетки не должны побеждать...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вначале вопросы по дизайну

1. Зачем хранить массив строк если достаточно массива байт? А при отрисовке рисовать уже тот символ, который нужен
2. Зачем передавать массив из метода в метод, если его можно сделать полем класса?

Итого

```java
class Desc {
  private int size;
  private byte[][] desc;

  public Desc(int ASize) {
    size = ASize;
    desc = new byte[size][size];
  }

  private boolean checkWinner() {
    return checkWinnerHorizontal() ||
      checkWinnerVertical() ||
      checkWinnerDiagonals();
  }

  private boolean checkWinnerHorizontal() {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      boolean res = true;
      for (int j = 1; j < size && res; j++)
        res = desc[i][j] == desc[i][0];
      if (res)
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  private boolean checkWinnerVertical() {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      boolean res = true;
      for (int j = 1; j < size && res; j++)
        res = desc[j][i] == desc[0][i];
      if (res)
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  private boolean checkWinnerDiagonals() {
    boolean res = true;
    for (int i = 1; j < size && res; i++)
      res = desc[i][i] == desc[0][0];
    if (res)
      return true;
    res = true;
    for (int i = 1; j < size && res; i++)
      res = desc[size - i - 1][i] == desc[size - 1][0];
    return res;
  }
```

Comment: Спасибо! У вас самый простой и понятный новичку вариант. Сделал на его основе свой.

Comment: @Павел в таком случае "передавайте привет" проблемам "победили пустые клетки" и "кто-то победил, но кто - неизвестно", которые тянутся от вашего вопроса сюда и, видимо, теперь обратно к вам.

Comment: Да нет все нормально. Я этот код не копировал и стринги на чары переделал и заполнил пустыми строками. Мне не нужен был код мне была нужна идея. Но что-бы простая.

Answer (score 4):

Цикл для проверки одной линии (в методе `check`) и циклы для проверки групп линий (в методе `checkAll`):

```
private static class GotWinnerException extends Exception
{
    private final char winnerType;

    public GotWinnerException(char winnerType)
    {
        this.winnerType = winnerType;
    }
}

private static final int
        FIELD_SIZE = 4,
        WIN_COUNT = 3;

private static final char EMPTY_CELL = ' ';

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    char[][] desc = new char[FIELD_SIZE][FIELD_SIZE];
    desc[0] = new char[] { '0',        'x', '0',        EMPTY_CELL };
    desc[1] = new char[] { EMPTY_CELL, 'x', '0',        EMPTY_CELL };
    desc[2] = new char[] { EMPTY_CELL, '0', 'x',        EMPTY_CELL };
    desc[3] = new char[] { EMPTY_CELL, '0', EMPTY_CELL, 'x' };
    char result = checkAll(desc);
    if (result != EMPTY_CELL)
    {
        System.out.println("Winner: " + checkAll(desc));
    }
}

public static char checkAll(char[][] desc)
{
    char winner = EMPTY_CELL;
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < FIELD_SIZE; i++)
        {
            check(desc, 1, 0, 0, i); //columns
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < FIELD_SIZE; i++)
        {
            check(desc, 0, i, 1, 0); //rows
        }
        check(desc, 1, 0, 1, 0); //first diagonal
        check(desc, -1, FIELD_SIZE - 1, 1, 0); //second diagonal
    }
    catch (GotWinnerException e)
    {
        winner = e.winnerType;
    }
    return winner;
}

public static void check(char[][] desc, int xCoef, int xShift, int yCoef, int yShift)
        throws GotWinnerException
{
    char savedSymbol = EMPTY_CELL;
    int savedSymbolCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < FIELD_SIZE; i++)
    {
        int x = i * xCoef + xShift;
        int y = i * yCoef + yShift;
        char symbol = desc[x][y];
        if (symbol == savedSymbol)
        {
            savedSymbolCount++;
        }
        else
        {
            savedSymbol = symbol;
            savedSymbolCount = 1;
        }
        if (symbol != EMPTY_CELL && savedSymbolCount == WIN_COUNT)
        {
            throw new GotWinnerException(symbol);
        }
    }
}
```

`FIELD_SIZE` задаёт размер стороны поля, `WIN_COUNT` - необходимое для победы количество подряд идущих клеток на одной линии.

Для теста используется поле 4х4 и 3 символа для победы. В данном случае `x` выигрывает по диагонали.

Answer (score 3):

Я бы написал так:

```
class Position {
    public int x, y;
    public Position(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

Position[][] winningTriples = {
    { new Position(0, 0), new Position(1, 0), new Position(2, 0) },
    { new Position(0, 1), new Position(1, 1), new Position(2, 1) },
    { new Position(0, 2), new Position(1, 2), new Position(2, 2) },

    { new Position(0, 0), new Position(0, 1), new Position(0, 2) },
    { new Position(1, 0), new Position(1, 1), new Position(1, 2) },
    { new Position(2, 0), new Position(2, 1), new Position(2, 2) },

    { new Position(0, 0), new Position(1, 1), new Position(2, 2) },
    { new Position(0, 2), new Position(1, 1), new Position(2, 0) }
};

boolean checkWinner(String[][] desc) {
    return Arrays.stream(winningTriples).anyMatch(triple ->
        Arrays.stream(triple).allMatch(
            item -> desc[triple[0].x][triple[0].y].equals(desc[item.x][item.y])));
}
```

(Надеюсь, не напутал со Stream API.)

Comment: По идее, `Position[][] winningTriples` нужно создавать динамически под поле любого размера. По поводу Stream: у вас `triple` - это `String[]` (одна линия). Соответственно, `triple[0]`, равно как и `item`, - это `String`, у которого полей `x` и `y` нет.

Comment: @Regent: Странно, разве `triple` не `Position[]`?

Comment: @Regent: Ах да, тьфу, опечатка. Исправил ответ. Спасибо!

Comment: Ух ты! а что это за new Position(0, 0) это специальный класс в java для всяких действий на плоскости?

Comment: @Павел этот класс объявлен чуть выше в этом же коде.

Comment: @Regent: Ну да, `winningTriples` можно и вычислять. Они тоже легко на Streams ложатся.