# Минимизация блоков if-else

Tags: javascript, jquery, инспекция-кода

Это кусок кода игры "крестики-нолики", который нужно сделать более компактным!
Хотя оно и так работает)

```
//вы выиграли
if (arr1[0] === 1 && arr1[1] === 1 && arr1[2] === 1) {
    $("#vin").text("you win");
    $("#a0").css("background-color", "red");
    $("#a1").css("background-color", "red");
    $("#a2").css("background-color", "red");
    vinner = true;
} else if (arr1[3] === 1 && arr1[4] === 1 && arr1[5] === 1) {
    $("#vin").text("you win");
    $("#a3").css("background-color", "red");
    $("#a4").css("background-color", "red");
    $("#a5").css("background-color", "red");
    vinner = true;
} else if (arr1[6] === 1 && arr1[7] === 1 && arr1[8] === 1) {
    $("#vin").text("you win");
    $("#a6").css("background-color", "red");
    $("#a7").css("background-color", "red");
    $("#a8").css("background-color", "red");
    vinner = true;
} else if (arr1[0] === 1 && arr1[3] === 1 && arr1[6] === 1) {
    $("#vin").text("you win");
    $("#a0").css("background-color", "red");
    $("#a3").css("background-color", "red");
    $("#a6").css("background-color", "red");
    vinner = true;
} else if (arr1[1] === 1 && arr1[4] === 1 && arr1[7] === 1) {
    $("#vin").text("you win");
    $("#a1").css("background-color", "red");
    $("#a4").css("background-color", "red");
    $("#a7").css("background-color", "red");
    vinner = true;
} else if  (arr1[2] === 1 && arr1[5] === 1 && arr1[8] === 1) {
    $("#vin").text("you win");
    $("#a2").css("background-color", "red");
    $("#a5").css("background-color", "red");
    $("#a8").css("background-color", "red");
    vinner = true;
} else if (arr1[0] === 1 && arr1[4] === 1 && arr1[8] === 1) {
    $("#vin").text("you win");
    $("#a0").css("background-color", "red");
    $("#a4").css("background-color", "red");
    $("#a8").css("background-color", "red");
    vinner = true;
} else if (arr1[2] === 1 && arr1[4] === 1 && arr1[6] === 1) {
    $("#vin").text("you win");
    $("#a2").css("background-color", "red");
    $("#a4").css("background-color", "red");
    $("#a6").css("background-color", "red");
    vinner = true;
}


//вы проиграли
else if (arr1[0] === 0 && arr1[1] === 0 && arr1[2] === 0) {

    $("#vin").text("you low");
    $("#a0").css("background-color", "red");
    $("#a1").css("background-color", "red");
    $("#a2").css("background-color", "red");
    vinner = true;
} else if (arr1[3] === 0 && arr1[4] === 0 && arr1[5] === 0) {
    $("#vin").text("you low");
    $("#a3").css("background-color", "red");
    $("#a4").css("background-color", "red");
    $("#a5").css("background-color", "red");
    vinner = true;
} else if (arr1[6] === 0 && arr1[7] === 0 && arr1[8] === 0) {
    $("#vin").text("you low");
    $("#a6").css("background-color", "red");
    $("#a7").css("background-color", "red");
    $("#a8").css("background-color", "red");
    vinner = true;
} else if (arr1[0] === 0 && arr1[3] === 0 && arr1[6] === 0) {
    $("#vin").text("you low");
    $("#a0").css("background-color", "red");
    $("#a3").css("background-color", "red");
    $("#a6").css("background-color", "red");
    vinner = true;
} else if (arr1[1] === 0 && arr1[4] === 0 && arr1[7] === 0) {
    $("#vin").text("you low");
    $("#a1").css("background-color", "red");
    $("#a4").css("background-color", "red");
    $("#a7").css("background-color", "red");
    vinner = true;
} else if  (arr1[2] === 0 && arr1[5] === 0 && arr1[8] === 0) {
    $("#vin").text("you low");
    $("#a2").css("background-color", "red");
    $("#a5").css("background-color", "red");
    $("#a8").css("background-color", "red");
    vinner = true;
} else if (arr1[0] === 0 && arr1[4] === 0 && arr1[8] === 0) {
    $("#vin").text("you low");
    $("#a0").css("background-color", "red");
    $("#a4").css("background-color", "red");
    $("#a8").css("background-color", "red");
    vinner = true;
} else if (arr1[2] === 0 && arr1[4] === 0 && arr1[6] === 0) {
    $("#vin").text("you low");
    $("#a2").css("background-color", "red");
    $("#a4").css("background-color", "red");
    $("#a6").css("background-color", "red");
    vinner = true;
}
```

Вот [ссылка всего кода](https://codepen.io/xlabuchik/pen/pwZaww?editors=1111) и если у вас еще есть идеи как сделать, чтобы комп думал более логически, подскажите.

```js
(function addLink(links) {
  links.reduce((head, l) => {
    var el = document.createElement('link');
    el.href = l;
    el.rel = "stylesheet";
    head.insertBefore(el, head.firstElementChild);
    return head;
  }, document.querySelector('head'))
})(["https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css", "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css", "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"].reverse());
$(document).ready(function() {
  var flag;
  var vinner;
  var winCombo = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6]
  ];
  var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
  var arr1 = [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3];
  var testArr = [];
  var nar1;

  function rand() {
    return nar1[Math.floor(Math.random() * nar1.length)];
  }
  $(".xo").click(function() {
    if (vinner === true) {
      return false;
    }
    if (flag === undefined) {
      alert('To start, click Start GAME and select "X" or "O"')
    }
    var a = $(this).text();
    var b = parseInt($(this).attr("data-value"));
    if (a === "") { //если пустая клетка
      $(this).text(flag);
      testArr.push(b);
      arr1[b] = 1;
      nar1 = arr.filter(el => testArr.indexOf(el) === -1);
      var randNumb = rand();
      idItem = '#a' + randNumb;
      testArr.push(randNumb);
      var f_map = {
        "X": "O",
        "O": "X"
      }
      $(idItem).html(f_map[flag]);
      arr1[randNumb] = 0;
    }

    //вы выиграли
    if (arr1[0] === 1 && arr1[1] === 1 && arr1[2] === 1) {
      $("#vin").text("you win");
      $("#a0").css("background-color", "red");
      $("#a1").css("background-color", "red");
      $("#a2").css("background-color", "red");
      vinner = true;
    } else if (arr1[3] === 1 && arr1[4] === 1 && arr1[5] === 1) {
      $("#vin").text("you win");
      $("#a3").css("background-color", "red");
      $("#a4").css("background-color", "red");
      $("#a5").css("background-color", "red");
      vinner = true;
    } else if (arr1[6] === 1 && arr1[7] === 1 && arr1[8] === 1) {
      $("#vin").text("you win");
      $("#a6").css("background-color", "red");
      $("#a7").css("background-color", "red");
      $("#a8").css("background-color", "red");
      vinner = true;
    } else if (arr1[0] === 1 && arr1[3] === 1 && arr1[6] === 1) {
      $("#vin").text("you win");
      $("#a0").css("background-color", "red");
      $("#a3").css("background-color", "red");
      $("#a6").css("background-color", "red");
      vinner = true;
    } else if (arr1[1] === 1 && arr1[4] === 1 && arr1[7] === 1) {
      $("#vin").text("you win");
      $("#a1").css("background-color", "red");
      $("#a4").css("background-color", "red");
      $("#a7").css("background-color", "red");
      vinner = true;
    } else if (arr1[2] === 1 && arr1[5] === 1 && arr1[8] === 1) {
      $("#vin").text("you win");
      $("#a2").css("background-color", "red");
      $("#a5").css("background-color", "red");
      $("#a8").css("background-color", "red");
      vinner = true;
    } else if (arr1[0] === 1 && arr1[4] === 1 && arr1[8] === 1) {
      $("#vin").text("you win");
      $("#a0").css("background-color", "red");
      $("#a4").css("background-color", "red");
      $("#a8").css("background-color", "red");
      vinner = true;
    } else if (arr1[2] === 1 && arr1[4] === 1 && arr1[6] === 1) {
      $("#vin").text("you win");
      $("#a2").css("background-color", "red");
      $("#a4").css("background-color", "red");
      $("#a6").css("background-color", "red");
      vinner = true;
    }

    //вы проиграли
    else if (arr1[0] === 0 && arr1[1] === 0 && arr1[2] === 0) {
      $("#vin").text("you low");
      $("#a0", "#a1", "#a2").css("background-color", "red");
      vinner = true;
    } else if (arr1[3] === 0 && arr1[4] === 0 && arr1[5] === 0) {
      $("#vin").text("you low");
      $("#a3").css("background-color", "red");
      $("#a4").css("background-color", "red");
      $("#a5").css("background-color", "red");
      vinner = true;
    } else if (arr1[6] === 0 && arr1[7] === 0 && arr1[8] === 0) {
      $("#vin").text("you low");
      $("#a6").css("background-color", "red");
      $("#a7").css("background-color", "red");
      $("#a8").css("background-color", "red");
      vinner = true;
    } else if (arr1[0] === 0 && arr1[3] === 0 && arr1[6] === 0) {
      $("#vin").text("you low");
      $("#a0").css("background-color", "red");
      $("#a3").css("background-color", "red");
      $("#a6").css("background-color", "red");
      vinner = true;
    } else if (arr1[1] === 0 && arr1[4] === 0 && arr1[7] === 0) {
      $("#vin").text("you low");
      $("#a1").css("background-color", "red");
      $("#a4").css("background-color", "red");
      $("#a7").css("background-color", "red");
      vinner = true;
    } else if (arr1[2] === 0 && arr1[5] === 0 && arr1[8] === 0) {
      $("#vin").text("you low");
      $("#a2").css("background-color", "red");
      $("#a5").css("background-color", "red");
      $("#a8").css("background-color", "red");
      vinner = true;
    } else if (arr1[0] === 0 && arr1[4] === 0 && arr1[8] === 0) {
      $("#vin").text("you low");
      $("#a0").css("background-color", "red");
      $("#a4").css("background-color", "red");
      $("#a8").css("background-color", "red");
      vinner = true;
    } else if (arr1[2] === 0 && arr1[4] === 0 && arr1[6] === 0) {
      $("#vin").text("you low");
      $("#a2").css("background-color", "red");
      $("#a4").css("background-color", "red");
      $("#a6").css("background-color", "red");
      vinner = true;
    }


  })
  //сброс поля
  $("#reset").click(function() {
    $(".xo").css("background-color", "#C1B2E9");
    $("#vin").text("");
    $(".xo").text("");
    arr1 = [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3];
    testArr = [];
    vinner = false;
  })
  //старт игры
  $("#start").click(function() {
    vinner = false;
    $(".xo").css("background-color", "#C1B2E9");
    $("#vin").text("");
    $(".xo").text("");
    arr1 = [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3];
    testArr = [];
    $("#table").hide(1300);
    var tes = setTimeout(function() {
      var div = document.createElement('div');
      div.className = "alert row cointeiner ";
      div.innerHTML = "<p>choose</p><button id='qX' class='btn knop1'>X</button><p>or</p><button id='qO' class='btn knop1'>O</button>";
      document.body.appendChild(div);
      $("#qX").click(function() {
        $(".xo").text("");
        $("#table").show(1300);
        flag = "X";
        div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
      })
      $("#qO").click(function() {
        $(".xo").text("");
        $("#table").show(1300);
        flag = "O";
        div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
      })
    }, 1400);
  })
});
```

```css
body {
  background: url("http://www.dinosaurlifestyle.com/prod_img/zoom/GGLFS013000_04_L.jpg") no-repeat;
  color: black;
  background-size: 100%;
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
}

.xo {
  width: 33%;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0.3%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

#table {
  padding: 0.3%;
  background: #C1B2E9;
  margin-top: 10%;
}

.row {
  margin: auto;
}

.knop {
  background-color: #E9E060;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 38px;
  margin: auto;
}

.knop:hover {
  background: #FFA91E;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 40px;
  box-shadow: 10px 0px 10px 0px #00FFA9;
}

.alert {
  background-color: red;
  margin: auto;
  width: 70%;
  padding: 0.3%;
  margin-top: 10%;
  font-size: 60px;
}

.knop1 {
  background-color: #69DB5E;
  font-size: 50px;
  border-radius: 45%;
  margin: auto;
}

#vin {
  font-size: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Frijole|Lobster|Pacifico|Monoton" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="vin"></div>
<div class="container" id="table">
  <div class="row">
    <button type="button" id="start" class="btn knop">Start GAME</button>
    <button type="button" id="reset" class="btn knop">RESET</button>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="xo" id="a0" data-value="0"></div>
    <div class="xo" id="a1" data-value="1"></div>
    <div class="xo" id="a2" data-value="2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="xo" id="a3" data-value="3"></div>
    <div class="xo" id="a4" data-value="4"></div>
    <div class="xo" id="a5" data-value="5"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="xo" id="a6" data-value="6"></div>
    <div class="xo" id="a7" data-value="7"></div>
    <div class="xo" id="a8" data-value="8"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2FNdR/

Comment: Как минимум, селекторы перечислять через запятую, а не на новой строке каждый

Comment: Тут интересный вариант - https://github.com/hkan/tic-tac-vue/blob/master/resources/assets/js/components/TicTacToe.vue#L93

Comment: онто интересный но мнебы хотелось както свой  через метод сделать убрать кучу ненужных иф

Comment: @xlabuchik используйте циклы для проверки горизонтальных, вертикальных и диагональных линий. Может, конечно, кто-то перепишет ваш код и добавит как ответ (лично мне сейчас точно некогда), но пока что предложу [ещё один вариант](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/608924/183458), от меня. Он на Java, для задаваемых размера поля и длины линии победы, а также для, в принципе, произвольного количества игроков. Однако несмотря на, возможно, излишнюю для вас гибкость, хотя бы идею отсутствия дублирования кода проверки почерпнуть из кода можно.

Comment: Посмотрите вариант такой https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bRyZPz?editors=1111

Comment: Стоит также подумать под названиями переменных, сейчас какие-то `arr1`,`nar1`, которые непонятно для чего используются и что хранят.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В предоставленном куске кода можно выделить две абсолютно одинаковые части. Перед ними даже комментарии стоят: *вы выиграли* и *вы проиграли*

Единственное их отличие - это число, с которым идет сравнение (1,0) и выводимый текст.

Поэтому одинаковую часть можно вынести в функцию:

```
vinner = checkState(1, 'win');
if(!vinner) vinner = checkState(0, 'low');
```

где `checkState` будет иметь следующий вид:

```
function checkState(player, text){
    if (arr1[0] === player && arr1[1] === player && arr1[2] === player) {
        $("#vin").text(text);
        $("#a0").css("background-color", "red");
        $("#a1").css("background-color", "red");
        $("#a2").css("background-color", "red");
        return true;
    } else if (arr1[3] === player && arr1[4] === player && arr1[5] === player) {
        $("#vin").text(text);
        $("#a3").css("background-color", "red");
        $("#a4").css("background-color", "red");
        $("#a5").css("background-color", "red");
        return true;
    } else if (arr1[6] === player && arr1[7] === player && arr1[8] === player) {
        $("#vin").text(text);
        $("#a6").css("background-color", "red");
        $("#a7").css("background-color", "red");
        $("#a8").css("background-color", "red");
        return true;
    } else if (arr1[0] === player && arr1[3] === player && arr1[6] === player) {
        $("#vin").text(text);
        $("#a0").css("background-color", "red");
        $("#a3").css("background-color", "red");
        $("#a6").css("background-color", "red");
        return true;
    } else if (arr1[1] === player && arr1[4] === player && arr1[7] === player) {
        $("#vin").text(text);
        $("#a1").css("background-color", "red");
        $("#a4").css("background-color", "red");
        $("#a7").css("background-color", "red");
        return true;
    } else if  (arr1[2] === player && arr1[5] === player && arr1[8] === player) {
        $("#vin").text(text);
        $("#a2").css("background-color", "red");
        $("#a5").css("background-color", "red");
        $("#a8").css("background-color", "red");
        return true;
    } else if (arr1[0] === player && arr1[4] === player && arr1[8] === player) {
        $("#vin").text(text);
        $("#a0").css("background-color", "red");
        $("#a4").css("background-color", "red");
        $("#a8").css("background-color", "red");
        return true;
    } else if (arr1[2] === player && arr1[4] === player && arr1[6] === player) {
        $("#vin").text(text);
        $("#a2").css("background-color", "red");
        $("#a4").css("background-color", "red");
        $("#a6").css("background-color", "red");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Можно заметить, что цифры в селекторах совпадают с цифрам в условии `if`, при этом сами блоки `if` отличаются только этими цифрами, поэтому их можно вынести в функцию:

```
function checkCombo(player, text, point1, point2, point3){
    if (arr1[point1] === player && arr1[point2] === player && arr1[point3] === player) {
        $("#vin").text(text);
        $("#a2").css("background-color", "red");
        $("#a4").css("background-color", "red");
        $("#a6").css("background-color", "red");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

И функция `checkState` примет вид:

```
function checkState(player, text){
    return (checkCombo(player, text, 0, 1, 2)  // winCombo[0] = [0, 1, 2]
        || (checkCombo(player, text, 3, 4, 5)  // winCombo[1] = [3, 4, 5]
        || (checkCombo(player, text, 6, 7, 8)  // winCombo[2] = [6, 7, 8]
        || (checkCombo(player, text, 0, 3, 6)  // winCombo[3] = [0, 3, 6]
        || (checkCombo(player, text, 1, 4, 7)  // winCombo[4] = [1, 4, 7]
        || (checkCombo(player, text, 2, 5, 8)  // winCombo[5] = [2, 5, 8]
        || (checkCombo(player, text, 0, 4, 8)  // winCombo[6] = [0, 4, 8]
        || (checkCombo(player, text, 2, 4, 6); // winCombo[7] = [2, 4, 6]
}
```

Теперь видно, что параметры `points` совпадают с уже существующим массивом winCombo.

Следовательно вместо ручного перебора можно использовать цикл:

```
for(var i=0; i<winCombo.length;i++){
    if(checkCombo(player,text,winCombo[i][0],winCombo[i][1],winCombo[i][2])) return true;
}
```

Передавать по индексам не очень удобно, поэтому можно просто передать сам элемент массива `winCombo`

```
for(var i=0; i<winCombo.length;i++){
    if(checkCombo(player,text,winCombo[i])) return true;
}
```

При этом изменится функция `checkCombo`

```
function checkCombo(player, text, line){
    if (arr1[line[0]] === player && arr1[line[1]] === player && arr1[line[2]] === player) { ... }
    return false;
}
```

Что происходит внутри `if` - для каждого элемента массива `line` проверяется условие, для этого у массивов есть специальный метод [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every). С ним условие можно переписать так:

```
if(line.every(point=>arr1[point]===player))
```

Далее отметим, что в функции, которая просто проверяет есть ли заполненная линия, еще выводится текст и закрашивают ячейки. Их можно вынести во внешнюю функцию `checkState`, в этом случае `checkCombo` упростится до следующего вида:

```
function checkCombo(player, line){
    return line.every(point=>arr1[point]===player);
}
```

И это выражение так же можно вынести наружу и убрать функцию:

```
function checkState(player, text){
    for(var i=0; i<winCombo.length;i++){
        if(winCombo[i].every(point=>arr1[point]===player))) {
            $("#vin").text(text);
            ...
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Для выделения ячеек можно воспользоваться тем, что `id` элементов совпадают с номерами в том же массиве `winCombo`, поэтому на его основе можно собрать нужный селектор, например:

```
winCombo[i].map(point=>`#a${point}`).join(',');
```

---

При более внимательном просмотре можно заметить цикл внутри `checkState` просто проверяет, есть ли в массиве `winCombo` хотя бы один элемент удовлетворяющий условию и производит с найденным элементом какие-то действия. Для этого у массивов есть специальная функция [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), при ее использовании получим

```
return winCombo.find(combo=> combo.every(point=> arr1[point]==player));
```

При этом установка текста и закраска ячеек может быть вынесена наружу.

В итоге саму `checkState` так же можно убрать, оставив одно условие.

Тексты можно хранить в объекте, тогда конечный вариант проверки может быть таким:

```
var players={
    '0':'you low',
    '1':'you win'
}
for(var player in players){
    vinner = winCombo.find(combo=> combo.every(point=> arr1[point]==player));
    if(vinner){
        $("#vin").text(players[player]);
        $(vinner .map(point=>`#a${point}`).join(',')).css("background-color", "red");
        break;// дальше нет смысла проверять
    }
}
```

Итоговый пример:

```js
(function addLink(links) {
  links.reduce((head, l) => {
    var el = document.createElement('link');
    el.href = l;
    el.rel = "stylesheet";
    head.insertBefore(el, head.firstElementChild);
    return head;
  }, document.querySelector('head'))
})(["https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css", "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css", "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"].reverse());
$(document).ready(function() {
  var flag;
  var vinner;
  var winCombo = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6]
  ];
  var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
  var arr1 = [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3];
  var testArr = [];
  var nar1;

  function rand() {
    return nar1[Math.floor(Math.random() * nar1.length)];
  }
  $(".xo").click(function() {
    if (vinner === true) {
      return false;
    }
    if (flag === undefined) {
      alert('To start, click Start GAME and select "X" or "O"')
    }
    var a = $(this).text();
    var b = parseInt($(this).attr("data-value"));
    if (a === "") { //если пустая клетка
      $(this).text(flag);
      testArr.push(b);
      arr1[b] = 1;
      nar1 = arr.filter(el => testArr.indexOf(el) === -1);
      var randNumb = rand();
      idItem = '#a' + randNumb;
      testArr.push(randNumb);
      var f_map = {
        "X": "O",
        "O": "X"
      }
      $(idItem).html(f_map[flag]);
      arr1[randNumb] = 0;
    }

    var players = {
      '0': 'you low',
      '1': 'you win'
    };
    for (var player in players) {
      vinner = winCombo.find(combo => combo.every(point => arr1[point] == player));
      if (vinner) {
        $("#vin").text(players[player]);
        $(vinner.map(point => `#a${point}`).join(',')).css("background-color", "red");
        break; // дальше нет смысла проверять
      }
    }


  })
  //сброс поля
  $("#reset").click(function() {
    $(".xo").css("background-color", "#C1B2E9");
    $("#vin").text("");
    $(".xo").text("");
    arr1 = [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3];
    testArr = [];
    vinner = false;
  })
  //старт игры
  $("#start").click(function() {
    vinner = false;
    $(".xo").css("background-color", "#C1B2E9");
    $("#vin").text("");
    $(".xo").text("");
    arr1 = [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3];
    testArr = [];
    $("#table").hide(1300);
    var tes = setTimeout(function() {
      var div = document.createElement('div');
      div.className = "alert row cointeiner ";
      div.innerHTML = "<p>choose</p><button id='qX' class='btn knop1'>X</button><p>or</p><button id='qO' class='btn knop1'>O</button>";
      document.body.appendChild(div);
      $("#qX").click(function() {
        $(".xo").text("");
        $("#table").show(1300);
        flag = "X";
        div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
      })
      $("#qO").click(function() {
        $(".xo").text("");
        $("#table").show(1300);
        flag = "O";
        div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
      })
    }, 1400);
  })
});
```

```css
body {
  background: url("http://www.dinosaurlifestyle.com/prod_img/zoom/GGLFS013000_04_L.jpg") no-repeat;
  color: black;
  background-size: 100%;
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
}

.xo {
  width: 33%;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0.3%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

#table {
  padding: 0.3%;
  background: #C1B2E9;
  margin-top: 10%;
}

.row {
  margin: auto;
}

.knop {
  background-color: #E9E060;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 38px;
  margin: auto;
}

.knop:hover {
  background: #FFA91E;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 40px;
  box-shadow: 10px 0px 10px 0px #00FFA9;
}

.alert {
  background-color: red;
  margin: auto;
  width: 70%;
  padding: 0.3%;
  margin-top: 10%;
  font-size: 60px;
}

.knop1 {
  background-color: #69DB5E;
  font-size: 50px;
  border-radius: 45%;
  margin: auto;
}

#vin {
  font-size: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Frijole|Lobster|Pacifico|Monoton" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="vin"></div>
<div class="container" id="table">
  <div class="row">
    <button type="button" id="start" class="btn knop">Start GAME</button>
    <button type="button" id="reset" class="btn knop">RESET</button>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="xo" id="a0" data-value="0"></div>
    <div class="xo" id="a1" data-value="1"></div>
    <div class="xo" id="a2" data-value="2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="xo" id="a3" data-value="3"></div>
    <div class="xo" id="a4" data-value="4"></div>
    <div class="xo" id="a5" data-value="5"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="xo" id="a6" data-value="6"></div>
    <div class="xo" id="a7" data-value="7"></div>
    <div class="xo" id="a8" data-value="8"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: большое спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Много букв TL;DR

Comment: @Alex78191, на то она и инспекция

Answer (score 2):

Все эти условия можно занести в цикл, поскольку у вас уже есть переменная *winCombo*

```
function showResult(text,a1,a2,a3){
      $("#vin").text(text);
      $("#a"+a1+",#a"+a2+",#a"+a3).css("background-color", "red");
      vinner = true;
  }
  for(var i=0;i<winCombo.length;i++){
    var a1 = winCombo[i][0],
        a2 = winCombo[i][1],
        a3 = winCombo[i][2];

    if(arr1[a1]=== 1 && arr1[a2] === 1 && arr1[a3] === 1){
          showResult('you win',a1,a2,a3);
          break;
       }
    //вы проиграли
      if(arr1[a1] === 0 && arr1[a2] === 0 && arr1[a3] === 0){
         showResult('you loose',a1,a2,a3);
          break;
       }

  }
```

Полный пример на https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bRyZPz?editors=1111

Answer (score 2):

А вот как полностью может выглядеть весь ваш код, если его и правда оптимизировать:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
let flag;
let vinner;
let winCombo = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6]
];
let arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
let arr1 = [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3];
let testArr = [];
let nar1;

$(".xo").click(function() {
    if (vinner === true) {return false}
    // Сокращённая запись(Если левый операнд до && равен false, то правый операнд даже не будет вычислен, потому, что всё выражение ложно):
    (flag === 'undefined') && alert('To start, click Start GAME and select "X" or "O"');
    let b = parseInt($(this).attr("data-value"));
    if ($(this).text() === "") {//если пустая клетка
        $(this).text(flag);
        testArr.push(b);
        arr1[b] = 1;
        nar1 = arr.filter(el=> testArr.indexOf(el) === -1);
        let randNumb = rand();
        idItem = '#a' + randNumb;
        testArr.push(randNumb);
        let f_map = {
            "X": "O",
            "O": "X"
        }
        $(idItem).html(f_map[flag]);
        arr1[randNumb] = 0;
    }

    // Код написанный Stepan Kasyanenko. Начало:
    for(var i=0;i<winCombo.length;i++){
        var a1 = winCombo[i][0],
            a2 = winCombo[i][1],
            a3 = winCombo[i][2];

        if(arr1[a1]=== 1 && arr1[a2] === 1 && arr1[a3] === 1){
            showResult('you win',a1,a2,a3);
            break;
        }
        if(arr1[a1] === 0 && arr1[a2] === 0 && arr1[a3] === 0){
            showResult('you loose',a1,a2,a3);
            break;
        }
    }
   // Код написанный Stepan Kasyanenko. Конец.
})

//сброс поля
$("#reset").click(function() {
    ResetXO();
    vinner = false;
})

//старт игры
$("#start").click(function() {
    // Сброс красного поля (дублирования) при повторном нажатии старта
    $('.alert').remove();
    vinner = false;
    ResetXO();
    $("#table").hide(1300);

    setTimeout(function() { // Здесь ненужно создавать лишнюю переменную
        // Коли взялись за jQuery - то уж будьте любезны его и использовать: :)
        // Создаём нужные классы и присоединяем к body
        $('<div>', {class: 'alert row cointeiner'}).appendTo('body');
        $('.alert').append("<p>choose</p><button id='qX' class='btn knop1'>X</button><p>or</p><button id='qO' class='btn knop1'>O</button>");
        showXO($("#qX"), 'X');
        showXO($("#qO"), 'O');
    }, 1400);
})

function showResult(text,a1,a2,a3){
    $("#vin").text(text);
    $("#a"+a1+",#a"+a2+",#a"+a3).css("background-color", "red");
    vinner = true;
}

function rand() {
    return nar1[Math.floor(Math.random() * nar1.length)];
}

function ResetXO(){
    $(".xo").css("background-color", "#C1B2E9").empty(); // лучше делать так
    $("#vin").empty(); // лучше делать так
    arr1 = [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3];
    testArr = [];
}

function showXO(obj, fl){
    obj.click(function() {
        $(".xo").text("");
        $("#table").show(1300);
        flag = fl;
    })
}
```

});

Comment: Я не понял, почему Вы взяли мой код и выдали его за свой?

Comment: Ни в коем случае ... ваш код - тот который оптимизирует условие if-else ... а мой -тот что оптимизирует всё остальное ... 
Я думал всем и так это понятно ... но раз есть ваше недоволство , я прям в коде сейчас укажу где именно ваш код, чтобы отпали все вопросы.

Comment: Ну в том то и дело. У вас вчера был совсем другой ответ, который предлагал использовать *switch* и что-то там еще... Ну в общем не важно, все равно у @Grundy ответ гораздо лучше наших))